# How to kill a running process on windows from nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, kill-process

I want to close chrome application on windows through nodejs.

Here what I did :

```
var ps = require('ps-node');
ps.lookup({ pid: 8092 }, function(err, resultList ) {
if (err) {
    throw new Error( err );
}

var process = resultList[ 0 ];

if( process ){

    console.log( 'PID: %s, COMMAND: %s, ARGUMENTS: %s', process.pid, process.command, process.arguments );
//process.kill(8092)
}
else {
    console.log( 'No such process found!' );
}
```

});

I am not able to kill the process. Can anyone suggest a way to do it.
I tried **process.exit()** **process.kill** **process.abort**, but nothing worked for me. It would be great if you help me out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just use `ps.kill`

```
ps.kill('8092', function( err ) {
    if (err) {
        throw new Error( err );
    }
    else {
        console.log( 'Process with pid 8092 has been killed!');
    }
});
```

you can check the [documentation](https://github.com/neekey/ps) for more info

Comment: Thanks for the help. One more thing is, can I do this lookup with name but not the PID of the process. If yes, what I should use?

Comment: You're doing a lookup with a PID, so you might have it to kill the process as well. In case you don't have it `ps.lookup` with give you a process and `process.pid` contains its pid to be used for `ps.kill`

Comment: Yeah I got your point, but I want to know is what should I use to do a lookup with process name not PIDs and then kill it with name itself?

Comment: You can't kill using the name. You might have more process with the same name. That's why you need the pid. So just do the lookup with name and kill with pid. The lookup gives you an array anyway, in case the query gives you more than one result.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`child_process.exec()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) to call `taskkill`. The below snippet uses the [`taskkill`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/taskkill) command and killing a process with either a PID or filename of an exe.

```
const {exec} = require('child_process')

const pid = 8092

// example app name 
const appName = 'firefox.exe' 

// Kills a PID and all child process
exec(`taskkill /pid ${pid} /t`, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (err) {
      throw err
    }

    console.log('stdout', stdout)
    console.log('stderr', err)
  })
})

// Kills a process based on filename of the exe and all child processes
exec(`taskkill /im ${appName} /t`, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (err) {
      throw err
    }

    console.log('stdout', stdout)
    console.log('stderr', err)
  })
})
```

Comment: i'm not sure `kill` is available on window. we use `taskkill` on windows right?

Comment: @TuanAnhTran Yeah my fault

Answer (score 0):

There's a npm package for that call `taskkill`

```
const taskkill = require('taskkill');

const input = [4970, 4512];

taskkill(input).then(() => {
    console.log(`Successfully terminated ${input.join(', ')}`);
});
```

Or you can take a look at that package and copy the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this is an npm package called tree-kill. And it will kill processes effectively.

```
var kill  = require('tree-kill');
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

var scriptArgs = ['myScript.sh', 'arg1', 'arg2', 'youGetThePoint'];
var child = spawn('sh', scriptArgs);

// some code to identify when you want to kill the process. Could be
// a button on the client-side??
button.on('someEvent', function(){
    // where the killing happens
    kill(child.pid);
});
```